# AngularJS sortable in multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, angularjs

I'm trying to find the best way to do something like JQuery sortable in Angular JS.
I know there is sortbale directive in angular-ui, but what I need is to be able to drag and drop items in multiple columns.

In JQuery this is done by `$(el).sortable({connectWith: '.column'});`

Is there a way to do that in Angular? As Angular newbie I don't want to play with JQuery sortable, as I know it doesn't fit Angular model well (DOM is manipulated in jQuery, outside Angular context, so it's tricky to have it synchronized).

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for the [orderBy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy) filter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include:

1. JQuery
2. JQueryUI
3. Angular

You need to create a directive:

```
directives.directive('sortable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.sortable({
                connectWith: ".column",
                start: function(event, ui) {},
                stop: function(event, ui) {},
                receive: function(event, ui) {}
            });
        }
    };
});
```

You need to apply the directive:

```
<div class="column" sortable></div>
```

In the example above the sortable can connect with the class column.